# Get the servername from a vhost with command line

Tags: bash, apache, shell, command-line

I'm searching for a particular command for a shell script and it's possible I don't understand correctly how Apache works.

I'm doing a build script for a installation of project for a local VM for the develop. Like we recover the prod database, we need to change the url in the dump of the database before to import it in local. I could inform manually the new URL in my script or pass it in option but I want to do a script which take all cases and be the more simple to launch.

I know which is the vhost on my local environment. So I want to know if it's possible to use a bash command to recover its servername.

The servername have generally this form:

[name_of_project].local
or
[name_of_project].[under_project].local

But it's not an absolute rule.

I looked the httpd command but I don't think something fix my problem. I searched on Internet but I find nothing about a command line. So I don't know if it's possible or if I will have to parse my conf file to recover my servername.

Thanks !

Comment: How that `url` looks like?...can you add it to your question?

Comment: Added.

name_of_project.local or name_of_project.under_project.local

But according to the person which configure the project, it's not always this format.